Writing subscript to subscript
I am trying to put subscript to subscript in the below term:
u_{{X}_{min}}

On compilation, it looks as below:

When you write the same terms using microsoft equation, it looks better and more accurate as X really looks as subscript of u and min as subscript of X as shown below:

How to get the similar kind of format to work in latex?

you've not provided any context. can you please provide code for a minimal document we can compile to reproduce the output you show?

Thank you for the response @cfr. I am actually making a research poster. So, I write equation and symbols in latex, and then convert the latex code equation into image as the publisher supports only images.

@mchaudh4 - Please see the answer I posted. I'd say that it might be a good idea to use parentheses to supply some additional, visual grouping to make sure that your readers will not be left in any doubt as to the meaning of the formula.

No, using the parenthesis would not look good @Mico. So, I think, latex cannot put X a little more down?

I would guess it ultimately has to do with different font parameters. Cambria sets ScriptPercentScaleDown to 73 while it is 70 in latin modern. For ScriptScriptPercentScaleDown cambria sets it to 60 while latin modern sets it to 50. Word uses cambria by default (looks like what you have). In TeX you probably get computer modern, but the latin modern should not differ too much in this respect. If you use opentype math, you can change the values. (Suggested values in the opentype math spec is 80 and 60.) Comparison

@mchaudh4 - You wrote, "I think, latex cannot put X a little more down". Wrong. Both u^{}_{X_{\min}} and {u^{}_X}_{\min} force a lower position of X relative to U. However, even after making this adustment, the following question remains: Which of the two possible formulas are you looking to typeset? I.e., is \min supposed to be a subscript of U^{}_X, or is X_{\min} supposed to be a subscript of u?

Thank you @mickep for the response. Yes, I am also think that the difference in subscripts is due to different font type in microsoft office equation and latex equation.

Context is crucially important here, as the double-subscript formula can have 2 meanings: (a) X_{min} -- X_{\min} would be better, actually -- is a subscript-type modifier of u; or (b) \min is a subscript-type modifier of u_X. Both meanings are conceivably correct.

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$u_{X_{\min}} \quad {u_X}_{\min}$
\end{document}

Given the formula you posted, case (a) would appear to apply. In contrast -- based on the screenshot you posted -- it looks like Microsoft Equation has somehow been led to express the view that case (b) applies. (Incidentally, I have no acquaintance whatsoever with Microsoft Editor; in particular, I have no idea what you typed in order to generate the second screenshot that's shown in your query.)
Unfortunately, your claim that "using microsoft equation, [the formula] looks better and more accurate" would appear to ignore the context entirely. If case (b) is supposed to apply, your formula is in error and should be rewritten as {u_X}_{\min}.
Aside: If you desire a larger vertical offset between u and X, that can be achieved by writing $u^{}_{X_{\min}}$ or ${u^{}_X}_{\min}$, respectively. Note that this issue is quite separate from the issue of the meaning of the formula.
Finally, if you're not sure whether your readers will understand which of the two cases is supposed to apply, it can't hurt to use parentheses to supply some unmistakable visual grouping.

$u_{(X_{\min})} \quad {(u_X)}_{\min}$

If the former case -- u_{(X_{\min})} -- applies, I can't help but further remark that there doesn't appear to be a need to place the (X_{\min}) term in a subscript position relative to u; i.e., you might as well write u(X_{\min}). Likewise, {(u_X)}_{\min} could be simplified to (u_X)_{\min}. Either way, you could avoid the inherently ambiguous use of two levels of subscripts.

$u(X_{\min}) \quad (u_X)_{\min}$


+1 for focussing on the ambiguity of double subscript notation.

One solution I also made, which i think can be useful using some part from the above solution.
It is basically reducing the font size of X because the main problem in the question is that the u is small and X is capital. Therefore, here it is seems essential to reduce the font size of X.
\usepackage{relsize}
    
$u_{\mathsmaller{X_{\mathsmaller{\min}}}}$ 

I hope, it helps.

While this change succeeds in making X and \min smaller than in u_{X_{\min}}, it doesn't resolve the question of the meaning of the formula: Is X_{\min} a modifier of u, or is \min a modifier of u_X? You seem to favor the former interpretation. Is this the case?

Hi @Mico. I really donot know much latex. I am making a research poster in which we first write equations in latex, and then convert it into image  using this website https://www.quicklatex.com/.  The basic meaning of the notation is X_min is a boundary point of a PDE and u is the value at the boundary point. To show that u is the value at the boundary point, we have used a notation X_min as subscript of u. Equation generated using this notation $u_{\mathsmaller{X_{\mathsmaller{\min}}}}$ somewhat serves our purpose. Thank you for great help.

Thanks for the additional information. Do please keep an open mind about writing the formula as $u(X_{\min})$. It might make the details of the research poster more readable than $u_{\mathsmaller{X_{\mathsmaller{\min}}}}$ can.

Thank you @Mico for great help.
